# Why there is a need to acces the children for getting the last element in $("body")

Tags: jquery, html, dom

```
$("body").last().find("button")
```

**and**

```
$("body").children().last().find("button")
```

**$("body").last().find("button")** gets all the buttons in the body tag not only buttons in the last element.

but

**$("body").children().last().find("button")** Gets only the buttons from the last div element inside the body.

Why there is need to children() to be processed to get the buttons in the last div element?

Comment: You want get last button of body childs?

Comment: I want to get all the buttons in the last child(div) in the body section @Mohammad

Comment: Use `$("body > div:last button")`

Comment: Thank you so much :) @Mohammad

Comment: Got it @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`last`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) gets the last item in the jQuery set you call it on. `$("body")` is a set containing the `body` element, so `$("body").last()` is pointless, it just gives you a set containing the `body` element again.

> ...to get the buttons in the last div element...

If you want to get the buttons in the last div, you can use jQuery's non-standard [`:last` selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) and a descendant combinator (a space):

```
$("div:last button")
```

...or find all `div` elements, take the last one, and find buttons within it:

```
$("div").last().find("button")
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reponse got it now :)

Answer (score 1):

`last()` gets the last element in a set.

`$('body')` matches the `<body>` element. There can only be one of those in an HTML document.

The last body is the only body.

Comment: Yep, Got it now, Thanks @Quentin